# How to trace the origin of a Javascript (XHR) generated HTML element with Chrome's Web Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, web-developer-toolbar

I am interested in an HTML page that uses an XHR object to request JSON data from the server and then some Javascript (jQuery) code is used to translate these data into HTML-markedup elements.

I wonder if it is possible to trace the "origin" of some HTML element using Chrome Web Developer Tools. That is, I want to understand if a specific element has been generated by some Javascript code and if so, which one, which line, and through which XHR object. I couldn't find a way. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have control over the code making the ajax requests ?

Comment: Control only in a limited sense. I see JavaScript being loaded in the Network Tab, as I can see all the XHRs.

Comment: If this html element has a specific id or class you can search for it in developer tools inside sources tab by pressing cntr+shift+F and find the code that created that element. If you find another way, please post. It would be good to know.